# Overlay transparent button on div

Tags: html, css

My goal is to overlay a transparent button on a div.  When a user clicks the button, the underlying div should change color.  I tried using z-index, but the button is not clickable.  Are there any additional CSS properties I could try that would help me achieve the desired functionality?

CSS:

```
#container{
        height:200px;
        width:200px;
        position:relative;
        z-index:auto;
    }
    #MyHiddenButton{
        float:left;
        height:100px;
        width:200px;
        z-index:2;
        background-color:transparent;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        outline: none;
        border: none;
    }
    #myContent{
        position:absolute;
        float:left;
        height:200px;
        width:200px;
        background-color:lightslategrey;
        z-index:1;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="myContent" runat="server"></div>
    <asp:Button ID="MyHiddenButton" runat="server" OnClick="MyHiddenButton_Click" />
</div>
```

C# Code:

```
protected void MyHiddenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myContent.Style.Add("background-color", "red");
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure your JS is okay ?

Comment: This might just be me. But what is CS code?

Comment: @Jay C# or C-Sharp :P

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson Yeah.. I did wonder. Just not seen it called CS and google didn't enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to using JQuery, you can just skip the hidden button and make the div clickable

```
$('#myContent').click(function(){
   $('#myContent').css('background-color','red'); 
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8sg5arq7/1/)